# Is this a valid top expression in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

I am reviewing an old code base and I have come across this SQL statement:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    3 As 'StatusCode'   
FROM 
    something a 
JOIN
    other bs on --etc.
```

My SQL is a bit rusty and is this just awful code that will always return 3 or am I missing something?

Comment: `will always return 3` - only if the following query actually returns rows. Otherwise it will return no rows. A proper way of doing it is `select 3 as StatusCode where exists (select * from something a Join  other bs on --etc)`.

Comment: Even in 2005, this can be written more clearly as `SELECT TOP(1) StatusCode = 3 FROM Something JOIN ...`, using explicit parentheses for the `TOP` and computed column syntax for `StatusCode`. Note that *as written*, your query is *not* legal -- it could be `[StatusCode]` or `"StatusCode"`, but not `'StatusCode'`, as the latter is a string literal, not an identifier.

Comment: @JeroenMostert `select 3 As 'StatusCode'` is valid (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-2017, feature ID 184)

Comment: @GSerg: I stand uncomfortably corrected. (Uncomfortably because `'StatusCode'` without an `AS` or computed expression *is* a string literal, so this just adds more room for confusion. Of course, it's not like T-SQL is in short supply of that.)

Answer (score 1):

It is truly hideous code but perfectly valid. There are many ugly things there for sure. But your interpretation of the results, and the quality, are spot on.

Answer (score 0):

It's valid SQL. I'm not quite sure if it's useful, but it's definitely valid.

Let's break it down.

For every row the join and/or other conditions return, the select list returns the literal `3` with the alias of `StatusCode`.
Then, it takes the top 1 row of those, which is obviously 3, as you stated.

TL;DR, assuming the join and other conditions actually return something, you'll get a single row with a column called `StatusCode` and the value 3.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, code is written just to check the existence of data under certain criteria and needing only one row (to validate condition). That's why it's hard coded using `TOP` and I think `DISTINCT` will also work in the same way but we don't change such a code in any other ways.